# How do I force a shutdown even when there are other open sessions?

Tags: shutdown, users, session

Well, hello, this is my first time using ubuntu and I have seen that when I try to turn off the computer when other user sessiong is running it doesn't do nothing. Then I have to enter that user session and close it or turn off in it to do it work.

sorry if I use a bad english, it's because it isn't my native languaje.

thanks.

Comment: Please update your question to state which version of Ubuntu you're using.

Comment: This is a basic linux question, so I don't think it's relevant which version s/he's using.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your account is an administrator on the computer (i.e. you have "root" or *sudo* privileges) this is very simple. Just open a terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T`, and type:

```
sudo reboot
```

Enter your password when prompted, and the computer *will shut down*, regardless of what other sessions are open. Unsaved data in any applications open in the other sessions (or in yours) **will be lost**.

If you wish to only shutdown and not restart, the alternative is:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

> Note: if you *do not* have sudo privileges, then you cannot do this. You can only shutdown when no other sessions are open; if they are, "shut down" will simply log you out.